# WPF Databound object changed in code not reflected in UI

Tags: wpf, data-binding

WPF-MVVM beginner here.
My problem: in a WPF-MVVM UI I am editing an entity. Some properties when changed, require automatic updates on other properties. These are done in Entity class, set methods, but not reflected in my View

More details:
1) I have the Model (a simple class with properties) in a separate assembly (not WPF related since is the general business model). Note that "SomeOption" when set to false, requires some other options to automatically be changed.
Example:

```
public class Employee : BaseEntity
    {
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        ....
    private bool someOption
        public bool SomeOption {
           get
           { return someOption}
            set {
                someOption= value;

                if (!value)
                {

                    OtherOption = false;
                    OtherProperty= "";
                    AndAnotherOption= false;

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

2) The WPF UI has a base ViewModel implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. The current edited record (Employee) is a public property of the ViewModel:

```
public Employee SelectedEmployee

{
    get { return _selectedEmployee; }
    set
    {

        if (_selectedEmployee != value)
        {
            _selectedEmployee = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedEmployee));

        }
    }
}
```

3) When un-checking the checkbox bound to "SomeOption", the other properties which are changed in entity code, are not reflected on the View, and stay on the screen as edited by user.

Please let me know what I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your model to update entities at your UI. For example:

```
public class Employee : BaseEntity, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string employeeNumber;
    public string EmployeeNumber { 
      get{return employeeNumber};
       set
          { 
             employeeNumber=value;
             OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeNumber");
          } 

    //...Other properties...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
       var handler = PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null)
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }           
}
```

Comment: My plan for this project was to have the Model completely separate, and interface agnostic, assuming that it might get one WPF UI, but possible a Web interface as well. How would I do that in this case?

Comment: @KeithJones  You cannot avoid implementation `INotifyPropertyChanged` in model class, if you want to see UI to be updated in MVVM. However, I cannot figure out problems, if you use this model class by Web interface. please, tell about some problems if you will use this class for Web interface.

Comment: In the meantime I've been reading more. I kind of assumed that INotifyPropertyChanged  is WPF related, that's why I didn't want to put it in the Model, but it turns out it is not. So I guess I could re-think the project. I am just starting with WPF-MVVM but the impression so far is that it is an idealistic concept which would be great, and it, in theory, but is not supported but the implementation. Starting to wonder if I should stick with WinForms....

Comment: @KeithJones try to use Ed Plunkett approach written in his comment. You should just ask your new question with clear questions and intentions what you want.

Comment: @KeithJones I found WPF to have a somewhat painful learning curve (and the quality of the documentation certainly didn't help), but after putting in a couple of years on it, I dread the thought of being limited to WinForms again. WPF is enormously powerful.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, thanks. Can you put a number on how many months until you get a little more productive? I'm at it for over a month and still feel like I can hardly do anything. I have a lot of years of experience as a developer, so this is a little bit of a shock, because whatever I learned before, it was always faster. It's true that I am laying the bases of a big project, so I don't want to just get it to work, I'm trying to do it right, with a good structure (hence the MVVM and trying to be as clean and "pure" as possible)

Comment: @KeithJones I think it took me something like a year of working with XAML to start to really "get it", but that was interrupted by a year long employment gap in the middle during which I thought I didn't want to be a programmer any more. Early on I worked through a PluralSight video course that gave me a big boost. Relative to winforms, it's much harder to learn just by rubbing against it a lot, because the concepts are so different. That was a problem for me, since I prefer to learn by doing.

Comment: @KeithJones yeah, Ed Plunkett is really right! I've learned WPF and Prism with Pluralsight and practise and many stupid questions at stackoverflow and WPF MSDN forum. Do not be shy to ask questions and never give up. We are here to help you!:)

Answer (score 1):

`Employee` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` just as your viewmodel does, and fire `PropertyChanged` on changes to its own properties (the ones you're calling `OtherOption`, `OtherProperty`, etc.)

What you've got now will update the UI when the view model selects a different `Employee`, but subsequent changes to that `Employee` don't send any notifications.

Comment: Same reply as for the other answer: My plan for this project was to have the Model completely separate, and interface agnostic, assuming that it might get one WPF UI, but possible a Web interface as well. How would I do that in this case?

Comment: @KeithJones Right, yeah. There isn't a really clean option for that. People usually end up writing a wrapper VM around the model class that just wraps notified accessor properties around the plain model properties. In our code base at work we've got dozens of classes like that. I wish there were a better way.